# Reference UIViewController within ContainerView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin, container-view

I have created a ContainerView in Xamarin, which automatically created a new ViewController.

[image]

I have created the class for this called Test1ViewController:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace test1
{
    public partial class Test2ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public Test2ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to reference this view controller in the ViewDidLoad() method of the main view controller. However if I put the following:

```
Test2ViewController.PresentViewController(picker, true, null);
```

I get a static error message, which makes sense as I am trying to reference the class not the specific object. Am I missing something, how do I reference the UIViewController in the ContainerView from the parent UIViewController?

What I am trying to achieve, is including the Scandit Barcode scanner within the container view:

```
        // Setup the barcode scanner
        var picker = new ScanditSDK.SIBarcodePicker ("API-KEY");
        picker.OverlayController.Delegate = new BarcodeScanner ();

        Test2ViewController.PresentViewController(picker, true, null);
        picker.StartScanning ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that variable **picker** is supposed to represent a Test2ViewController instance:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
  base.ViewDidLoad();

  this.picker = new Test2ViewController(); 
  this.PresentViewController(picker, true, null);  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have added further clarification of what the picker is to my question.

Comment: @Joseph What do you mean with ContainerView?

Comment: My understanding is I have added a Container View (the blue part of the diagram), which auto generated the Test2ViewController. What I want is for the barcode scanner (picker) to fill the blue area on my diagram.

Comment: @Joseph Is BarcodeScanner derived from UIView or from UIViewController?

Comment: picker.view is derived from UIView